# Crystal Reports - Check for Lowercase or Uppercase

Tags: crystal-reports, report, uppercase, lowercase

I need to identify a field value that has both Lowercase and Uppercase values, which are used to define a flag status. If the lowercase value exists or is null, then i need to see it, else it is considered completed.

Alternatively, if it is Uppercase, then mark as completed and then i can just add that as a formula to exclude all "not equal to" completed.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on the [SAP forums](https://answers.sap.com/questions/5211409/searching-a-string-field-for-capital-letters.html), that can identify whether the value is between the range of lowercase values or uppercase values.

//For Uppercase values

```
ascw({field})>=65 and ascw({field})<=90
```

//For Lowercase Values

```
ascw({field})>=97 and ascw({field})<=122
```

Final code worked by creating a formula value with the below and then selecting all "Unmatched" values

```
if ascw({GACCENTRYD.MTC_0}) >=65 and ascw({GACCENTRYD.MTC_0}) <=90 then 'Matched' else
if ascw({GACCENTRYD.MTC_0}) >=97 and ascw({GACCENTRYD.MTC_0}) <=122 then 'UnMatched' else
'UnMatched'
```

Answer (score 0):

In Crystal, go to File, Report Options...

Turn off '***Database Server is Case-Insensitive***' option.
Then, use a simple expression such as:

```
If Ucase({status}) = {status} Then "Completed" ELSE "Not Completed";
```